# After I remove all the children of a ParentNode. The parentnode becomes null?

Tags: c#, xml, parent-child

My goal is to remove all children from a parent so I end up with only the parent.
This is the OuterXml of Parent:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Parent xmlns="http://www.null.nl/zero">
   <SpeedIndicator exists="True"/>
</Parent>
```

When I remove the child I get this in the OuterXml:

```
<Parent xmlns="http://www.null.nl/zero"></Parent>
```

I remove the children like this:

```
RemoveAllChildren(node.ParentNode);

public static string RemoveAllChildren(XmlNode xmlNode)
        {
           
            while (xmlNode.HasChildNodes)
            {
                xmlNode.RemoveChild(xmlNode.FirstChild);
            }
            return xmlNode.OuterXml;
        }
```

But if I debug to check the new value of ParentNode.OuterXml. ParentNode has become null.

```
  var whatgives = node.ParentNode.OuterXml;
```

I've tried RemoveAll on the ParentNode with the same result. What should I do to have the ParentNode I desire?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Here is [Microsoft's description of the `XmlNode.ParentNode` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.parentnode?view=net-7.0): "The `XmlNode` that is the parent of the current node. If a node has just been created and not yet added to the tree, or if it has been removed from the tree, the parent is `null`."

Comment: What is wrong with the first solution?  It is the correct solution.

Comment: "ParentNode.OuterXml. ParentNode has become null." don't you mean `OuterXML` is null? The *C#* stack reference to the `ParentNode` should be fine.

Comment: @ΩmegaMan
 Thanks. ParentNode is null. Apparently I can't change ParentNode or any of its elements/attributes without breaking ParentNode. OuterXml before trying to assign it looks as mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce the error. I ran a fiddle and it outputs the OuterXml as expected. I tried to remove the children nodes 3 different ways. Perhaps you need to check the contents of the `node` variable to make sure it contains what you expect before calling `RemoveAllChildren`. See fiddle:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        
        string xmlText = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><Parent xmlns=\"http://www.null.nl/zero\"><SpeedIndicator exists=\"True\"/></Parent>";
            
        //Debugging
        Console.WriteLine(xmlText);
        
        //Load the XML string into an XmlDocument
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xmlText);
        
        //Get the first child named "Parent"
        XmlNode node = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Parent")[0];
        
        //Remove all the children nodes.
        node.RemoveAll();
        
        //Output the remaining OuterXml
        Console.WriteLine(node.OuterXml);
        
        //Try again, reload the xml.
        doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xmlText);
        
        //Get the first child named "Parent"
        node = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Parent")[0];
        
        //Different method to remove children.
        while (node.HasChildNodes)
        {
            node.RemoveChild(node.FirstChild);
        }
        
        //Output the remaining OuterXml
        Console.WriteLine(node.OuterXml);
        
        //Third Try using function, reload the xml.
        doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xmlText);
        
        //Get the first child named "Parent"
        node = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Parent")[0];
        
        //Output the returned string.
        Console.WriteLine(RemoveAllChildren(node));
    }
    
    public static string RemoveAllChildren(XmlNode xmlNode)
    {
        while (xmlNode.HasChildNodes)
        {
            xmlNode.RemoveChild(xmlNode.FirstChild);
        }
        return xmlNode.OuterXml;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I should use fiddle more often. However the difference is that in my code I take the node.ParentNode. The xml I put up is what is in node.ParentNode. The ParentNode is ofcourse another node of the node in question. I'm just not familiar with updating xml. And you cannot assign to ParentNode nor to OuterXml. So its not a bug or anything but ignorance on my part. Assigning something to InnerXml also makes ParentNode null.

Comment: I missed the part where you were deleting children from `node.ParentNode`. That means that there's a variable that still has a pointer to the child when you try to delete the child. As you found out, that can't be done.